# Best way to Import/Export data from a DB while bypassing Active Record Validation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, import, export

I have a large console query that calls 130 objects and all their associated objects in total of about 2,000 items.

I'd like to somehow export the raw SQL data of this query so that I can inject that raw data into another database.

Is there a gem, or strategy to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Hos about taking dump of the db and restore?

Comment: Maybe you could use the `#to_sql` method to get the raw query, and save that

Comment: The entire db is 6.8 gigabytes. It would be unnecessary. I only need certain records. Also `to_sql` doesn't return sql for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need active record validation, I'd recommend just using mysql:

If your query is simple (or can be broken down into multiple simple queries), you can use the [--where option of mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) to export the data you wish and then reimport it with the standard mysql client:

```
mysqldump db_name --where "id IN (1, 3, 5)" > export.sql
mysql new_db < export.sql
```

I don't think mysqldump supports queries with join, so if you have a more complicated query, you could use mysql's [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) query to export the data to a csv, then [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) to import it.

Comment: Should also note that the default export sql actually will drop your table before injection.